# Is there a pattern to force the setting of a property in an injected component?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am wondering if there is a pattern that forces the user of my component to set a property after it is autowired. For example i have this:

```
@SpringComponent
@PrototypeScope
public class MyAutowiredClass {

    private String myVariabeThatTheUserShouldSet;

    public MyAutowiredClass(someOtherStuff ...(not my StringVariable)){

    }
}
```

In this example how to i force myVariabeThatTheUserShouldSet to be set from the user of this component?

Comment: This looks like a design smell. Ensure at least that your component scope is not singleton

Comment: yeah the default scope is singleton in spring ;)

Comment: well this was a example, in my real code its prototype scoped, maybe i should have added that good catch :)

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's a bit complicated. If it wasn't in spring context you could just add that variable to the constructor and make it "required" like that.  So to achieve that in a Spring context I would advise the following:

1. If possible pass that value as part of the dependency injection instead of trying to work around it. I understand it is something dynamic but still usually it would have business meaning and there is a way to do it. For example if you want the current user email you can add some Service that retrieves that value and pass that service to your component and extract that value from there. Or if you want some company configuration you can add a Service that gives you that value etc. It is the "Spring" way and I would lean towards that.
2. A simpler solution would be to add that required field to the methods signature of the methods that actually need it. It will overload the signatures by one field but it would force the users to pass a value. If you need that field for a couple of methods and not for the correct work of the component then it would be the easiest to implement/understand solution.
3. Add a setter for that value and throw exception if it is not set. That would be the worse though because will require try/catches if the exception is checked and if it is not people will forget to set the field so I would avoid that solution.